# How to use vue plugin in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There's a plugin called vue-chat-scroll and I would like to use it in nuxt. Am a beginner so I cant really understand how but I wonder if its possible to use this vue plugin in nuxt as plugin. how would one do that?

Comment: Please add some code with expected behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a js file in plugin folder and name it vue-chat-scroll.js (the name is optional. It depends on you). then register your plugin inside this js file as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll';

 Vue.component('VueChatScroll', VueChatScroll);
```

Then import it in nuxt.config.js inside plugins as follow:

```
plugins: [
  {
    src: '~/plugins/vue-chat-scroll.js',
    ssr: true
   }
]
```

Comment: btw, ssr: true is legacy code it will depreciated in upcoming release. you should use mode : 'client' or mode : 'server' default value is mode : 'server'

Comment: Throws error "Failed to resolve directive: chat-scroll".

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file inside plugins folder, for example, vue-chat-scroll.js with the following content:

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll'
   Vue.use(VueChatScroll)
   ```
2. In nuxt.config.js import the plugin as

   ```
    plugins: [...your existing plugins,'~/plugins/vue-chat-scroll.js']
   ```

and then follow the plugin tutorial for its API

Comment: 'Vue.use' doesn't work for plugins in nuxt. You should use Vue.component('VueChatScroll', VueChatScroll);

Comment: https://github.com/theomessin/vue-chat-scroll
The library is not a component it is a directive. 
Also if this is a component it is not good idea to register the component globally. 
I don't know why the answer marked as accepted .

Comment: yep. i tried both and your one throws error "Failed to resolve directive: chat-scroll" as we can clearly see the library is not a component . it is a vue custom directive .